# Flask NoAppException

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a simple Flask app, but I get `flask.cli.NoAppException` if I try to start it with `flask run`. I simplified the code to literally few lines but I still get the same error:

`dashboards.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
server = Flask(__name__)
```

`.flaskenv`:

```
FLASK_APP=dashboards.py
FLASK_ENV=development
```

I have the file with `Flask` in the same directory where I run `flask run`:

[image]

(Moreover, I did one Flask app just few days ago and I did not have a problem like this.)

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Can you please share the complete error?

Answer (score 1):

The `FLASK_APP` environment variable should be set to `dashboards:server`, where `dashboards` is the name of the Python module (not file) and `server` is the name of the application instance.

With your current setup, Flask tries to import module `dashboard.py` (i.e. searches for file `dashboard/py.py`) and find an application instance with a standard name `app` or `application` or an application factory with a standard name `make_app` or `create_app`.

See more docs on `FLASK_APP` [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#application-discovery).

Comment: I was following one of the tutorials on Flask: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world (in the end it proposes to set the `FLASK_APP` to the file name. And actually this tutorial worked for me before... Also, if I rename `server` to a standard name `app`, I get the same error with both `dashboards.py` and `dashboards` as `FLASK_APP`.

Comment: If I run it with `python dashboards.py` command and `app.run(debug=True)` added to the code, it works. But I don't understand what is the problem with the environment variable.